# PoW custom consensus with remote calls

Tags: substrate-node-template, consensus

I'm trying to implement a new consensus in Substrate.

The consensus is similar to PoW but requires querying other nodes to generate the work/proof. Would implementing the PowAlgorithm trait and calling other nodes in the mine() function be a good way to implement this?

I would have to query multiple nodes one after another asking for signatures to build the proof. Like in "nonce mining PoW", the proof depends on the latest block hash and can be verified easily, so once it is produced, it would be submitted to the network in a similar way as a nonce in traditional PoW.

Where/how should I implement this in the whole Substrate framework ? Can I query peers from the PowAlgorithm trait mine() function and where should I implement the listening/answering end of such queries (I guess it would be a new custom rpc)? And what is the method to call a specific node RPC from another substrate node ?

What I would like to be able to do as a producer of a new block is:

- Get the list of all nodes in the network
- Select a subset of them with custom logic
- Query the subset of nodes asking them for signatures (one after the other, dependency between signatures)
- Once I have all the signatures, generate the proof from them
- Submit the block to the network with the proof (like a nonce in PoW)